# Laravel 5.3 - Type hinting two different request classes in method

Tags: php, request, laravel-5.3

I'm in the process of developing a web app and I've run into a problem where I need to validate form input. I've created a validation class according to the laravel docs and type-hinted the class in my method. The problem is that I've already got the Illuminate\Http\Request class type-hinted in my method and type-hinting my validation class in the same method brings up a "Forbidden" message when I refresh the page.

Validation class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ValidateCalculatorValues extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'deposit' => 'required|numeric',
            'months' => 'required|numeric',
            'interest' => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar;
use App\Http\Requests\ValidateCalculatorValues;

public function index($id, Request $request, ValidateCalculatorValues $calculatorInput, CookieJar $cookieJar)
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

How do I go about doing this so that it works? Am I missing something?

Comment: can you try changing the `authorize()` method in your class to `return true` ?

Comment: That seemed to solve the Forbidden response but now Firefox is telling me the page isn't redirecting properly. I suspect this is because there isn't any form data when the page is first loaded and so it's trying to redirect back to the same page and effectively creates an infinite loop. Is there a way I can set it not to do a check if there isn't any form data submitted?

Answer (score 1):

As phobia82 mentioned in the comments, I needed to set the authorize method on my validation class to true.

But because the form is posting to the same url that the form is on it was creating an infinite redirect loop because my validation rules were set so that all fields were required. After looking at the documentation, I changed "required" to "filled" which solved the redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `Request $request` in your parameter since your `ValidateCalculatorValues` will now handle the validation.

```
public function index($id, ValidateCalculatorValues $calculatorInput, CookieJar $cookieJar)
{
    $allYourInputs = $calculatorInput->all();
}
```

or you could do this for more convention

```
public function index($id, ValidateCalculatorValues $request, CookieJar $cookieJar)
{
    $allYourInputs = $request->all();
}
```